# Debug stepping not working after enabling then disabling "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm fairly new to programming and IDEs in general.  I was messing around in [Tools] [Options] [Debugging] in VS2010 and now my program is not stepping through the code as it was previously.  I checked the "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" option and then it attempted to dowload symbols.  Then I unchecked this option and now my program will not step back into the Form1 code after the form launches and a button is clicked.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the same settings, is "Enable Just My Code (Managed Only)" checked?  When you check "Enable .NET Framework source stepping", VS2010 will uncheck the other option (they are mutually exclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're still targeting x86 and try cleaning the project. For the first, right-click solution > properties > configuration properties. For the second, right-click solution > select clean